# Как сделать, чтобы виртуальная клавиатура не поднимала activity?

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы выезжающая снизу виртуальная клавиатура(по клику на EditText) не поднимала activity до верха своей границы, а просто поверх выезжала? У меня MapsActivity, но это наверно роли не играет..

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно в манифесте для активити указать атрибут android:windowSoftInputMode. Вам нужны 
значения adjustResize и/или adjustPan. Подробнее [вот тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php#moveactivity) можно почитать

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы изменялся размер по высоте только RecyclerView под виртуальную клавиатуру, выравнивался низ RV по верхнему краю клавиатуры, а все остальные View-ы не сдвигались?

Comment: нет, невозможно, насколько мне известно. Либо вы меняете размер корневого вью при открытии клавиатуры, либо рисуете клавиатуру поверх. В первом случае можно автоматически прокрутить активити так, чтобы активный editText точно был видим. Во втором случае нельзя определить высоту клавиатуры, чтобы своим кодом расположить ваш список как вам надо

Answer (score 1):

Можно в `onCreate` добавить строку

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

И клавиатура будет открываться в режиме "Наложения"